# How can I set a list inside a definition in latex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I need to write a definition that has a list of items.

```
    What is science : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                      - List item 1
                      - List item 2
                      - List item 3

                      Another lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

I have this but it doesn't do what's above:

```
\paragraph{What is science}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{itemize}
  \item List item 1
  \item List item 2
  \item List item 3
\end{itemize}
```

Here is the output:

```
    What is science : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    - List item 1
    - List item 2
    - List item 3
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? You should build a minimal working example that shows the problem and tell us which error you get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` environment or one of its variations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l@{\space}X}
What is science: & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\begin{itemize}
  \item List item 1
  \item List item 2
  \item List item 3
\end{itemize} \\
& Another lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using the `description` environment instead:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) as it provides more flexibility.
- [The `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) is needed for the `\widthof{}` macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=\widthof{\bfseries What is science:~}]
    \item [What is science:] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item List item 1
        \item List item 2
        \item List item 3
    \end{itemize}
    Another lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for record a solution with `minipage` without `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\wis}
\settowidth{\wis}{\bf What~is~science:~}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{What~is~science:~}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-\wis}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0ex}
  \item List item 1
  \item List item 2 
  \item List item 3
\end{itemize}
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]